# why the drop shadow hide when the element move

Tags: css

I have a dive with a drop shadow using

```
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #fff);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #fff);
```

but the drop shadow disappear when the element moves. why is that and how to prevent it.
the jsfiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/vu14anwv/
The problem show up in chrome, In fire fox every thing is OK.

Comment: could you please tell us the browser you are looking into, as given fiddle code works properly in Chrome and Firefox..

Comment: do you have any reason not to use the regular box-shadow ? https://jsfiddle.net/vu14anwv/1/

Comment: Yes the real shape is not square. it's a hexagon png file.

Comment: The version of my chrome browser is "Version 51.0.2704.103 m" is it an old version of chrome?

Comment: I my browser the shadow go away until the rotation ends and then come back.

Comment: Version 51 is not an old version.

Comment: seems like a bug you could report, even things like backface-visibility doesn't cure this unexpected behavior :(

Comment: It's a bug fixed in version 52

Comment: oki, then just allow chrome to update :)

Comment: Why don't you just use `box-shadow` instead?

Comment: I said why @TylerH , because the real shape in my website is not an square shape. It is a hexagon png file.

Comment: @coolesterman So why does your code you've shared not reflect the real code you are using? We can't debug pseudo code

Comment: because I don't know how to import my image to jsfiddle. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try a drop-shadow ON the element you want to appear under.

```
.element-that-is-to-be-under{
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #fff);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #fff);
}
```

Comment: Then I have to rotate it again and the same problem occur.